# Angular2 i18n language switch

Tags: angular, dynamic, typescript, internationalization, switching

I'm looking for a way to

- set dynamically the current language to be displayed: I have followed the latest angular cookbook [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html) about internationalization 
  but it says "*the user's language is hardcoded as a global document.locale variable in the index.html*"

How can this be set dynamically in angular2 + typescript ?

Here is my attempt from the official Angular2 plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/lWV4VhzpWYnCXeDBpzsn?p=preview
where I've commented out the

```
document.locale='en';
```

and tried to retrieve the window.document inside a typescript service, and change the locale there, but despite it is called and the locale set properly (seen in the console), the interface is not displayed in the chosen language **at startup**.

Then of course the dropdown buttons don't work either because the same erroneous way is used and the display is not refreshed but that is the next step.

Comment: In the meantime I have done a version which reads document.URL and sets the document.locale inside the i18n-providers.ts file.
It's certainly not the right way to  proceed but in the meantime I can carry on the translations stuff
https://plnkr.co/edit/TE7raLGC9pvYfaRu6Syg?p=preview
(This example does not work due on plunkr, but works locally)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am saving user selected language key into local storage:

```
//<select name="selectLocate" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
 public onChange(localeId: string): void {
    localStorage.setItem('localeId', localeId);
    location.reload(true);
  }
```

Then force reloading, and in `i18n.provider.ts`

```
let locale = localStorage.getItem('localeId');
```

Comment: simple and great. I have changed the plunkr example and it works fine! https://plnkr.co/edit/JyE4l4TjEruuPsrbanmK

Comment: I am not using systemsjs. Is it possible to configure it using webpack ?

Comment: @sardarCoder Don't know if you are still struggling with this, but if so. Yes you can: Just use the raw-loader to load xlf-files: `{test: /\.xlf/, loader: 'raw-loader'},`

Comment: @GOB raw-loader is a loader for webpack that lets you import files as a string. So?

Comment: What if I get settings on an app load and it contains the language I should use? I need the way to apply it wothout a page reload (don't want to get settings twice).

Comment: hi guys i have some error like this Argument of type '{ providers: Object[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(CompilerOptions & BootstrapOptions) | (CompilerOptions & BootstrapOptions)[]'.
  Type '{ providers: Object[]; }' is not assignable to type '(CompilerOptions & BootstrapOptions)[]'.
    Property 'includes' is missing in type '{ providers: Object[]; }'   can u tel me how can i fix this error my guide is plnkr.co/edit/JyE4l4TjEruuPsrbanmK