# Angular2 i18n language switch using Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, internationalization

I am looking to implement a run-time locale switch in my Angular 2 app. I found the following [Angular2 i18n language switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894394/angular2-i18n-language-switch) which contains a solution that uses SystemJS, https://plnkr.co/edit/JyE4l4TjEruuPsrbanmK.  My app uses webpack.  I am trying to use the raw-loader to load my xlf file but am getting "Error: cannot find module ./i18n/messages.es.xlf."  I think the problem may be related to this chunk of code in the i18n-providers.ts file.

```
declare var System: any;

function getTranslationsWithSystemJs(file: string) {
  return System.import(file); // relies on text plugin
}
```

What do I replace the preceding code with if using webpack?