# Nativescript Localize Dynamic Language Switching

Tags: localization, nativescript

Is it possible to dynamically switch language from within the Nativescript app.  I'm using the Nativescript Localize plugin.

I'm building a user preferences page where a user can select their preferred language from a drop down.

If it's not possible with Nativescript Localize, does anyone have any experience doing this with another method/plugin?

It appears there are Angular ways to do this so I was hoping they'd work but they seem to limited to the browser since they use localStorage.

- [Angular2 i18n language switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894394/angular2-i18n-language-switch)
- [angular 5 change locale dynamically for i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704797/angular-5-change-locale-dynamically-for-i18n)

Answer (score 1):

Switching the language programatically is not supported by the plugin, but the plugin can be modified to do that.

On iOS, instead of getting [main bundle](https://github.com/lfabreges/nativescript-localize/blob/master/src/localize.ios.ts#L11)) you could modify the plugin to get bundle based on your language preference, [here is an example written in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34131794/1060423).

Similarly for Android, you would have to get the [Resources based on your locale preference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475663/1060423) instead of the [active one](https://github.com/lfabreges/nativescript-localize/blob/master/src/localize.android.ts#L10).